Evaluating $ \int\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+x\sqrt{1-x^2})}\, dx $
I am trying to evaluate the indefinite integral of

$$ \int\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+x\sqrt{1-x^2})} \,dx $$

The first thing I tried was the substitution $$x=\sin(u),\ dx=\cos(u)\,du $$
The integral then transforms to
$$\int \frac{(\cos(u)-\sin(u))\cos(u)}{\cos(u)(1+\sin(u)\cos(u))}\,du $$
or
$$\int \frac{\cos(u)-\sin(u)}{1+\sin(u)\cos(u)}\,du $$
I'm a bit stuck here. May I ask for help on how to proceed?

Cheat

Note that
$$ \frac{\cos u-\sin u}{1+\sin u \cos u}
= \frac{(\cos u+\sin u)’}{1+\frac12 [(\cos u+\sin u)^2 -1]} $$

@Quanto thank you so much, this is a wonderful little observation. Would you write that in the form of an answer, though?

@MartinR thanks :) but I assume the method W|A used here is something I am unsure of if I'd like to use it in an exam.

@Aniii u r welcome

I like @Quanto's idea. But in general case you can use this substitution for such integrals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

If I expand the idea from that of Quanto then,
$$\frac{\cos u-\sin u}{1+(\sin u\cos u)}$$
We can expand the denominator as:
$$\frac 12 (2+2\sin u\cos u)=\frac 12(1+(\sin u+\cos u)^2)$$
Let $\sin u+\cos u=z$, then $\cos u-\sin u=dz$ and therefore,
$$
\frac{dz}{\frac 12(1+z^2)}=2\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=2\tan^{-1}(z)=2\tan^{-1}(\sin u+\cos u)+C
$$
If you want tangent half-angles, this seems to be a hard approach. Consider that:
$$\sin u=\frac{2\tan \frac u2}{1+\tan^2\frac u2}$$
$$\cos u=\frac{1-\tan^2\frac u2}{1+\tan^2\frac u2}$$
and therefore, we arrive at:
$$\frac{(1-\tan^2\frac u2-2\tan \frac u2)(1+\tan^2\frac u2)}{(1+\tan^2\frac u2)^2+(1-\tan^2\frac u2)(2\tan \frac u2)}$$
$$=\frac{(1-\tan^2\frac u2-2\tan \frac u2)(\sec^2\frac u2)}{(1+\tan^2\frac u2)^2+(1-\tan^2\frac u2)(2\tan \frac u2)}$$
You can resubstitute $\tan \frac u2=p$ and rewrite the whole integral again as:
$$
2\int\frac{(1-p^2-2p)}{(1+p^2)^2+(1-p^2)(2p)}dp
$$
that becomes much complicated as I think.

You should try to finish tangent half angle sub way.  You get more +1.

@BobDobbs I think that credit goes to Claude, he has advanced things up from there.

WolframAlpha gave a very interesting answer.  Maybe you can find the trick without looking at its answer. @M.Riyan

Claude's way is very long. I don't think he could  pass exam by spending all time for a single question.  @M. Riyan

Officiously, in a little longer way than Quanto's comment
$$\int \frac{\cos(u)-\sin(u)}{1+\sin(u)\cos(u)}\,du
$$
$$=\int \frac{(\cos^2(u)-\sin^2(u))\,du}{(1+\frac12\sin(2u))(\cos(u)+\sin(u))}$$
$$=\int \frac{2\cos(2u)\,du}{(2+\sin(2u))\sqrt{(\cos(u)+\sin(u))^2}}$$
$$=\int \frac{2\cos(2u)\,du}{(1+1+\sin(2u))\sqrt{1+\sin(2u)}}$$
$$\stackrel{1+\sin(2u)=v}{=}\int\frac{2d(\sqrt{v})}{1+(\sqrt{v})^2}$$
$$=2\arctan(\sqrt{v})+C$$
$$=2\arctan(\sqrt{1+\sin(2u)})+C$$
$$=2\arctan({\sin(u)+\cos(u)})+C$$
$$=2\arctan(x+\sqrt{1-x^2})+C$$

Thanks. This is a nice method too. +1

Using the tangent half-angle substitution
$$I=\int\frac{\cos (u)-\sin (u)}{1+\sin (u) \cos(u)}\,du=-2\int\frac{t^2+2 t-1}{t^4-2 t^3+2 t^2+2 t+1}\,dt$$ The denominator factor as
$$\left(t^2-\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right) t+2+\sqrt{3}\right)
   \left(t^2+\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) t+2-\sqrt{3}\right)$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$I=\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)\int \frac {dt}{t^2+\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) t+(2-\sqrt{3} )}-$$ $$\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)\int \frac {dt}{t^2-\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right) t+(2+\sqrt{3})} $$ which are more than simple.

Thank you for the answer. How did you come up with the factors of the denominator, though?

@Aniii. It must factor since the quartic shows four complex roots. So, write $$t^4-2 t^3+2 t^2+2 t+1=(t+a t+b),(t^2+c t +d)$$ Expand and identify the coefficients $(a,b,c,d)$ which must be real.

Oh, thanks, then. Didn't know about that (being in high school).

The integral in $t$ is the same one produced by applying Euler's second substitution to the original integral, $\sqrt{1 - x^2} = xt \pm 1$, i.e., $x = \mp \frac{2 t}{1 + t^2}$.

@TravisWillse. Very correct !

As an alternative to the standard tangent half-angle substitution, consider its relative
$$u=\tan\left(\frac\pi4-\frac\theta2\right) \iff \theta=\frac\pi2-2\arctan u$$
which boils down to further replacing $(*)$ $u=\dfrac\pi4+\theta$ in OP's attempt:
$$\begin{align*}
& \int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2} \left(1+x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)} \, dx \\
&= \int \frac{\cos u-\sin u}{1-\cos u\sin u} \, du = \sqrt2 \int\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi4-u\right)}{1-\frac12\sin(2u)}\,du & u=\sin x\\
&= -2\sqrt2 \int \frac{\sin\theta}{2+\cos(2\theta)} \, d\theta = 2\sqrt2 \int \frac{d(\cos\theta)}{1+2\cos^2\theta} & (*)\\
&= 2 \arctan \left(\sqrt2\,\cos\theta\right) + C \\
&= 2\arctan\left(\cos u+\sin u\right) + C \\
&= 2\arctan\left(\sqrt{1-x^2} + x\right) + C
\end{align*}$$
